# Creating a realistic world Series

Tags: discussion, reference

There are a series of questions that go through the process of creating a realistic world step-by-step.

> This is a series of questions that tries to break down the process of creating a world from initial creation of the landmass through to erosion, weather patterns, biomes and every other related topics. Please restrict answers to this specific topic rather than branching on into other areas as the other stages will be covered by further questions.

A list of all the questions in the series can be found below, so that a link to this meta post should be enough for future questions.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The main series of questions is the following

- [Creating a realistic world map - Landmass formation](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/581/creating-a-realistic-world-map-landmass-formation).
- [Creating a realistic world map - Erosion](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/1020/creating-a-realistic-world-map-erosion?lq=1).
- [Creating a realistic world map - Currents, Precipitation and Climate](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/1353/creating-a-realistic-world-map-currents-precipitation-and-climate?lq=1).
- [Creating a realistic world map - Coastlines](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21349/creating-a-realistic-world-map-coastlines?lq=1).
- [Creating a realistic world map - Waterways](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21402/creating-a-realistic-world-map-waterways?lq=1).
- [Creating a realistic world map - Underwater geography](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/23097/creating-a-realistic-world-map-underwater-geography).
- [Creating a realistic world map - Vegetation/Biomes](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/23941/creating-a-realistic-world-map-vegetation-biomes).
- [Creating a realistic world map - Mineralogy](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/25084/creating-a-realistic-world-map-mineralogy)
- [Creating a realistic world map - Fuel](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/25366/creating-a-realistic-world-map-fuel).
- [Creating a realistic world - Thermohaline circulation](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/25721/creating-a-realistic-world-thermohaline-circulation).
- [Creating a realistic world - Spreading languages](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/25396/creating-a-realistic-world-spreading-languages).
- [Creating a realistic world - Spreading religions](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/25478/creating-a-realistic-world-spreading-religions).
- [Creating a realistic world map - Countries Borders](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/23820/creating-a-realistic-world-map-countries-borders?rq=1).
- [Creating a realistic world - Governments](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/25524/creating-a-realistic-world-governements).
- [Creating a realistic world - Currency](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/56232/creating-a-realistic-world-economics)

---

Some spin-off questions were made and are listed here

- [Creating a realistic world(s) map - planetary systems](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/21408/creating-a-realistic-worlds-map-solar-systems?lq=1).
- [Creating a realistic world(s) map - Stars](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/23040/creating-a-realistic-worlds-map-stars?lq=1).

Comment: So it's been 6 months since last chapter of this serie? I really liked it, it helped me doing my world. But I feel like it isn't done. After creating governments, we need to create historical figures, events, economy, world relations, evolution of technologies...

Comment: Feel free to add a question to the list yourself. But note that some of those have been asked already... just not linked to that series...

Comment: Some are about maps, some are about worlds. Is this mainly for map-making or world-making? Everything above (as of time of writing) can be mapped, or plotted on a map, etc. But what about things that don't fit on a map that are part of world creation? Such as the kind of laws that a society might adapt, or the way a society would measure things like time, distance, volume, speed, and weight.

Comment: @InbarRose That's a good question, the two are linked really. You can't have a map without a world. If you have a world you probably have a map of some sort. The series has grown over time as people added branches etc.